# Google maps api with React

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3

I am currently working on a project and have tried multiple times to include clickable markers into my map. I have use google-maps-react library, however I have not managed to get a marker showing information and being able to click on a button on this information window. I have read that Marker by default isn't clickable but is there an other way to do so ? or are there any tutorials or code that explain so
thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .addListener() on a marker and tell it to open an infowindow (or whichever action you want to take on marker click).

You can find an example in the Google API documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows)

```
  // Add a marker to the map
  const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    // position of the marker on map
    position: { lat: 53.3, lng: -6.3 }, 
    // the map object you want the marker on
    map: map, 
  });

  // add a listener to the marker which listens for a 'click' 
  // and runs the callback when it 'hears' one
  marker.addListener('click', () => {
    // set the content of the info window. This can be formatted using HTML
    infowindow.setContent('I have been clicked!');
    // tells the infowindow on which map to open and which marker to anchor to
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
```